# Writing the html tags into dictionary with relations

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrap a html file and i am fairly successful in parsing the tag and text i need, however i am stuck with respect to storing the parsed data into a list or dict. The problem i am facing is that i don't want to remove the relation between the tag.

```
    <div class="Content-divs">
     <h3>
      RCTM
     </h3>
     <table class="content-table">
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>
         <div class="toggle-header">
          <h4 class="pull-left">
           <a href="########" target="_blank">
            Balanced Scorecard
           </a>
          </h4>
          <p class="pull-right">
           <a href="#######">
            Report Profile
           </a>
          </p>
          <div class="clearfix">
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="toggle-content">
          <p>
           <strong>
            Description:
           </strong>
           Provides an indicator of performance.
          </p>
          Owner:
         </div>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="even">
         <div class="toggle-header">
          <h4 class="pull-left">
           <a href="#######">
            Centralized Monitoring Metrics Dashboard (CMMD)
           </a>
          </h4>
          <p class="pull-right">
           <a href="###########">
            Report Profile
           </a>
          </p>
          <div class="clearfix">
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="toggle-content">
          <p>
           <strong>
            Description:
           </strong>
           The metrics in this dashboard are intended to provide
          </p>
         </div>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
```

If you see in the above html code the  tag is a parent tag under which there a multiple . i am interested in pulling this into the a dict or list while maintaining its relation.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
import sqlite3

c = 'Functions.html'
so = soup(open(c),'html.parser')
s1 = so.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'Content-divs'})
print(s1[0].prettify())
z = dict()
for a in s1:
    k = a.find_all('h3', string=True)
    k=str(k)
    k = re.findall('>(.*)<', k)
    v = a.find_all('h4', attrs={'class':'pull-left'})
    print(k)
    for b in v:
        b = b.find_all('a')
        b = str(b)
        c = re.findall('>(.*)<', b)
        print(c)
```

My expected result would be something like {'RCTM':'Balance Scorecard', 'RCTM:'Centralized Monitoring Metrics Dashboard (CMMD)'}

Comment: Can you show what your expected result would look like?

Comment: I would like to have a dictionary which would look something like below. {'RCTM':'Balance Scorecard', 'RCTM:'Centralized Monitoring Metrics Dashboard (CMMD)'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seem you are trying to capture text using regex but it not match because the string has newline and `re` missing `re.S` flag.

But I think what you need to extract text is `.text`

```
for a in s1:
    k = a.find('h3').text
    print(k.strip())
    v = a.find_all('h4', attrs={'class':'pull-left'})
    for b in v:
        b = b.find('a').text
        print(b.strip())
```

or simplified

```
z = []
for a in s1:
    k = a.find('h3').text
    for b in a.select('h4.pull-left a'):
        z.append({k.strip() : b.text.strip()})
print(z)
```

results

```
[
  {'RCTM': 'Balanced Scorecard'},
  {'RCTM': 'Centralized Monitoring Metrics Dashboard (CMMD)'}
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, i have been able to extract the text, however my problem is storing them in a dictionary. {'RCTM':'Balance Scorecard', 'RCTM:'Centralized Monitoring Metrics Dashboard (CMMD)'}

Comment: you cannot have same key in one dictionary it should be list of dict, see above.

Comment: Any idea how i can do that, i am very new to python